# How can i delete multi selected records using checkbox in Kendo Grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to allow the user to select one or more rows using checkbox in kendo grid and to delete the selected rows, my project is asp.net MVC

1. How can i add the checkbox in order to allow the user to select it?
2. How to delete all selected rows? i.e rows with selected checkbox

anyone can suggest me how can i do this?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikMvcAppCombo.Models.ImageModel>()


.Name("grdImageModel")


.Columns(columns =>

{
    columns.Bound(c => c.IMAGESIZE_NAME).Width(140);
    columns.Bound(c => c.IMAGESIZE_DESC).Width(140);
    columns.Bound(c => c.created_by);
    columns.Bound(c => c.created_date);
    columns.Bound(c => c.modified_by);
    columns.Bound(c => c.modified_date);
})
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 580px;" })
.Scrollable()
.Groupable()
.Sortable()
.Pageable(pageable => pageable
    .Refresh(true)
    .PageSizes(true)
    .ButtonCount(10)
)
.DataSource(datasource => datasource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read
            .Action("GetData", "Image")
          ))

)
```

Comment: Do you want to add checkbox dynmically?

Comment: not dynamically. i want to add simple checkbox in this kendogrid and delete them

Comment: What do you mean by add and delete?

Comment: add checkbox in kendo grid to all rows and after that i want to delete multiple delete in kendo grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kendo grid add this column

```
columns.Template(x => { }).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='chkSelect_#= yourid#' userId='#= yourid#' />").Width(20);
```

and lets say you have a button to delete records and when we click that button you can loop the data source and delete records. See the JavaScript example. You have to use jquery to do that

```
var grid, dataSource, data = null;
grid = $("#grdImageModel").data("kendoGrid"), dataSource = grid.dataSource, data = dataSource.data();

        $.each(data, function (i, tmpObject) {
            $('tr[data-uid="' + tmpObject.uid + '"] td input[id^="chkSelect_"]:checked').each(function (k, input) {
                // here you are access the checked row object
            });
        });
```

Comment: yes this is correct but i want to post all the selected checkbox row ids to action on form post. is it possible?

Comment: ajax post or normal form submit?

Comment: form submit without jquery